# Values above 2D array

Tags: equations, arrays, nicematrix

I want to put values above an array (see red circle on the 1st picture).
[image]

I made the matrix without the values (see 2nd picture).
[image]

Code of 2nd picture is here

```
\begin{eqnarray}
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
y_{+1}\\
\vdots\\
y_{+m}\\
y_1\\
\vdots\\
y_N
\end{array}
\right)
\sim
\mathcal{N}\left(
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
0\\
\vdots\\
0\\
0\\
\vdots\\
0\end{array}
\right),
\begin{array}{c}
{\bf x}_{+1}\\
\vdots\\
{\bf x}_{+m}\\
{\bf x}_{1}\\
\vdots\\
{\bf x}_{N}
\end{array}
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
 & & & & & \\
 &K_{+m}& & &K_{N,m}& \\
 & & & & & \\
 \hline
 & & & & & \\
 &K_{N,m}^\mathsf{T}& & &K_{N}& \\
 & & & & & 
\end{array}
\right)
\right)
\end{eqnarray}
```

Any suggestion is helpful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with `nicematrix` which has the advantage of giving a perfect alignment throughout the differents matrices (we need at least v. 5.10 of 2021-02-05).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}    
        
\begin{equation}
\begin{NiceArray}{ccccc@{\hspace*{7mm}}c|c}[first-row,baseline=line-4,cell-space-limits=5pt]
       &&        &&     & \mathbf{x}_1\cdots\mathbf{x}_N & \mathbf{x}_1^*\cdots\mathbf{x}_M^* \\
y_{+1} & \Block{6-1}{{}\sim\mathcal N\hspace*{1em}}& 0 &\Block{6-1}{,}& \mathbf{x}_{+1} & \Block{3-1}{K_{+m}} & \Block{3-1}{K_{N,m}} \\
\Vdots && \Vdots && \Vdots         & \hspace*{25mm} & \hspace*{25mm}\\
y_{+m} && 0      && \mathbf{x}_{+m} \\
\cline{6-7} 
y_1^*  && 0      && \mathbf{x}_1^* & \Block{3-1}{K_{N,m}^{\top}} & \Block{3-1}{K_N} \\
\Vdots && \Vdots && \Vdots         & \\
y_N^*  &\NotEmpty& 0       &\NotEmpty& \mathbf{x}_N^* & \\
\CodeAfter
\SubMatrix({1-1}{6-1})
\SubMatrix({1-3}{6-3})
\SubMatrix({1-6}{6-7})[left-xshift=3pt]
\SubMatrix({1-3}{6-7})[xshift=6pt,extra-height=6pt]
\end{NiceArray}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Unfortunately, my latex version (overleaf) is v. 5.0. So I cannot run your code. But Thank you for your simple and nice code!

Comment: @Mikado: You can retrieve the latest version of nicematrix.sty on the SVN server of TeXLive : `www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty` and upload that file in the repertory of your project in Overleaf.

Comment: @Pantigny Your guidance is very helpful, and I can run your code. It looks exactly what I want. Thank you very much!

Comment: This answer have my +1. For the future of your excellent package nicematrix. Why do you not created also the blocks also with the rectangle boxes? I have read in your mind...aahhahah :-)...You have edit your answer now.:-)

Answer (score 2):

The question can be answered using `tikz` to put a top row on top of the last matrix.

I used the `nicematrix` package because by defining the Tikz nodes in the cells and their corners, the package integrates very well with tikz. That way the code is much simpler and more compact.

[image: B]

I used it in all four arrays, although in fact only in the last one is really necessary.

The `\Block` command replaces `multicolumn` and `multirow`, so `\Block{3-2}` creates a centered 3x2 cell.

The environment allows the execution of tikz code, used in this case to put  the top row and draw the (thicker) lines. Note the use of `\mathbf` in math mode for bold face.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}    
        
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-top-limit=5pt,cell-space-bottom-limit=5pt}    
    
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{pNiceMatrix}
    y_{+1}\\
    \vdots\\
    y_{+m}\\
    y_1^\ast\\
    \vdots\\
    y_N^\ast
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\sim
\mathcal{N}
\left(
\begin{pNiceMatrix}[columns-width = 20pt]
    0\\
    \vdots\\
    0\\
    0\\
    \vdots\\
    0
\end{pNiceMatrix}
% \right)
 ,
\begin{NiceMatrix}[columns-width = 30pt]
    \mathbf{x}_{+1}\\
    \vdots\\
    \mathbf{x}_{+m}\\
    \mathbf{x}_{1}^{\ast}\\
    \vdots\\
    \mathbf{x}_{N}^{\ast}
\end{NiceMatrix}
\begin{pNiceArray}{cc  cc}[columns-width = 30pt,cell-space-top-limit=10pt,
                            cell-space-bottom-limit=10pt]
    \Block{3-2}{K_{+m}} &   & \Block{3-2}{K_{N,m}}  & \\
                                &   &                               & \\ 
                                &   &                               & \\ 
    \Block{3-2}{K_{N,m}^\mathsf{T}}&& \Block{3-2}{K_{N}}& \\
                                &   &                               & \\
                                &   &                               & \\
    \CodeAfter
    \tikz{%  put the top row and lines <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \node at (-3,2.5){\begin{tabular}{c} 
            $\mathbf{x}_{1} \cdots \mathbf{x}_{N}$  \hspace{25pt} $\mathbf{x}_{1}^\ast \cdots \mathbf{x}_{M}^\ast$ 
            \end{tabular}};
    \draw [thick]($(row-4-|col-1)!0.5!(row-4-|col-2)$) -- ($(row-4-|col-4)!0.5!(row-4-|col-5)$); 
    \draw [thick] ($(row-1-|col-3)!0.3!(row-2-|col-3)$) -- ($(row-6-|col-3)!0.7!(row-7-|col-3)$); 
    }
    \end{pNiceArray}
\right)
\end{eqnarray}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! That is the perfect solution!

Comment: @Simon Dispa: You sent me a mail. I replied but my answer has been returned... I answer here. You can find all the versions of `nicematrix.sty` on the SVN server of TeXLive : `www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty`

Comment: @ F. Pantigny Thank you!!